# getting device latitude and longitude showing null

Tags: android

While getting the latitude and longitude location on device, I am getting null in logcat.

But In genymotion emulator I am getting gps latitude and longitude location,if I turn on gps in the right side of genymotion emulator.

I don't know Why I can't get the latitude and longitude location in device.

Below I have posted the code relevant to that.

**Logcat:**

```
E:/ gpsLocation: null
```

**FragmentDiscovery.java:**

```
 AppLocationService appLocationService;

  appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getActivity());

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getLocation();

                Log.e("GET_USER_LAT_STR", ""+GET_USER_LAT_STR );
                Log.e("GET_USER_LON_STR", ""+GET_USER_LON_STR );


                editor.putString("GetLat", GET_USER_LAT_STR);
                editor.putString("GetLon", GET_USER_LON_STR);


                editor.commit();


                Fragment fragment = new CardsFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });




        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

   void getLocation(){

       Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
               .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

       Log.e("gpsLocation", ""+gpsLocation);

       if (gpsLocation != null) {
           double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
           double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();

           GET_USER_LAT_STR = String.valueOf(latitude);
           GET_USER_LON_STR = String.valueOf(longitude);

       } else {
           showSettingsAlert("GPS");
       }

   }

    public void showSettingsAlert(String provider) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alertDialog.setTitle(provider + " SETTINGS");

        alertDialog
                .setMessage(provider + " is not enabled! Want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

**Edit:**

In device it is not getting gpslocation.Instead simply showing turn on gps windows in settings.But I had already turned on gps

Comment: If you're trying to get location using GPS then it will take some times to fixed at least 3 satellites. time is around 20-30 sec or may be more depend on your device movement

Comment: @MD is there any alternate way to solve this issue? But in genymotion emulator it took one second to show the latitude and longitude location.But in device it is not getting gpslocation.instead simply showing the turn on gps.But I had already turned on gps

Comment: Use Google Location services for getting location.

Comment: Run google maps before running your app. it will trigger gps initilization for your emulator.

Comment: @MD ok let me try that one

Answer (score 0):

Use onLocationChanged for getting updated location.